# Returning query results on separate lines

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains user names.  I am trying to query the table and retrieve all names starting with the letter f.  There are 3 such names.  When the names are retrieved and displayed, the three results are on the same line.  I would like to change the code such that each of the three results is on a separate line.  The code that I am currently using is below.  Thank you in advance for any help!

```
<?php
$resultf = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name LIKE 'f%' ORDER BY name");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultf))
{
echo $row['name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `echo $row['name'] . '<br />';` inside the loop.

Comment: in here echo $row['name']; add a breakline echo $row['name']; echo '<br />';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
echo $row['name'],'<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

The br element represents a line break. So simply echo out a `HTML` line break in each iteration of the loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultf))
{
  echo $row['name']  . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $row['name']."<br />".PHP_EOL;
```

only BR is not enough, you should add PHP_EOL so PHP will automatically add end-of-line (mostly "\n")... Its necessary to show in multiple lines especially in view source (or anywhere HTML is not applicable).

Comment: pointless. PHP_EOL is the local system end-of-line character. It's utterly useless if the output is an html target, or some OTHER operating system with a different EOL char. e.g. Linux server outputting to a Windows-based browser. Double-whammy

Comment: I dont know... but its only neat if you have an EOL even if its HTML... Why? because vice versa your result will look like minified/compressed...

Comment: I ask OP to check difference with and without PHP_EOL... for debugging and other purposes, You might be checking "View Source" while developing project. Its really neat and handy!

Answer (score 0):

this also working fine

```
echo $row['name']."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `<br/>` tag , which is used for line break in HTML .

```
<?php
$resultf = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name LIKE 'f%' ORDER BY name");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultf))
{
echo $row['name'].'<br/>';//br tag used here.... 
}
?>
```